# How to access nested SASS variables?

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

Several colors in this .scss file are defined as such:

```
$colors: (
  primary :   #cd0e11,
  secondary:  #23aa0b,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222
);
```

How do I access them? Say I want to set something to primary.

I tried:

```
h1 {
color: $colors:primary
}
```

This is Ionic 2, so it could be a framework specific thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out this is called SASS mapping. The following will work. It works like a key value fetcher.

```
color: map-get($colors, primary)
```

Check [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-maps/) out for more info on it.

Comment: I wonder why the basic dot syntax doesn't work: $colors.primary

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
h1 {
   color: color($colors, primary);
}
```

Comment: Does this code compile? Is there a `color` function in sass?

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/theming-your-app/)

Comment: Oh it's an ionic function! Just realised the OP is also using ionic. Haven't worked with it. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the map, use the function map-get(). You can also loop through each one if necessary: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-sass-maps-usage-and-examples--cms-22184

```
$map: (
 color01: value,
 color02: nextValue,
 color03: thirdValue
); 

.element {
  content: map-get($map, color01);
}
```